# masstransit access Activity from service bus message

Tags: azure-application-insights, masstransit

I am using Masstransit to send Request/Response via servicebus between two services(dont ask why).

I would like to set-up custom application insights telemetry. I know that ServiceBus Messages add Diagnostic metadata so consumer can extract it and use it to add correlation between services. However I can't access it in MassTransit, or at least I dont know how.

Any tips?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of months passed and solution i implemented proves to be a good one.
I created class that implements IReceiveObserver. On PreReceive I am able to access (ServiceBusReceiveContext)context and start Telemetry operation that has correct parent id. so it looks like this:

```
    public Task PreReceive(ReceiveContext context)
    {
        var serviceBusContext = (ServiceBusReceiveContext)context;
        var requestActivity = new Activity("Process");
        requestActivity.SetParentId(serviceBusContext.Properties["Diagnostic-Id"].ToString());
        IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(requestActivity);
        operation.Telemetry.Success = true;
        serviceBusContext.Properties.Add(TelemetryOperationKey, operation);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

On PostReceive I am able to stop operation:

```
    public Task PostReceive(ReceiveContext context)
    {
        var serviceBusContext = (ServiceBusReceiveContext)context;
        var operation = (IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry>)serviceBusContext.Properties[TelemetryOperationKey];
        operation.Dispose();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I also do some magic when exception happens:

```
    public Task ReceiveFault(ReceiveContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        _telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
        var serviceBusContext = (ServiceBusReceiveContext)context;
        var operation = (IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry>)serviceBusContext.Properties[TelemetryOperationKey];
        operation.Telemetry.ResponseCode = "Fail";
        operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
        operation.Dispose();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

It was difficult to find this solution by reading MassTransit documentation. I would say that MassTransit is a fantastic tool for some situations there is no alternatives. However documentation is pretty poor.

Comment: You cannot write into serviceBusContext.Properties in the latest version. But actually, it is not needed if you use MassTransit filters (aka middleware). Check here: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Application Insights with MassTransit, there is a package available that writes metrics directly.

The documentation is available here:

https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/monitoring/applications-insights.html

*Also, you can access `Activity.Current` from anyway, I think, based on my experience with DiagnosticSource. It might be different with AppInsights though.*

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I tried using that extensions but it did not connect 2 services on Application map. I have service A that does request to service B. I want to be able to see that with automatic dependency tracking module on service B(windows service).
---


I of course can access Activity.Current on service B, but I need to access a dependencyTelemetry id of a servicebus 'Send' on service A and send it to service B to set it as RequestTelemetry.ParentId

Comment: Hey Chris, is there a way to intercept a serviceBus message MassTransit sends it from service A? OR, what would be even more useful - can I somehow receive a ServiceBus Message on a consumer side, service B - to use extension method of ServiceBus.Message .ExtractActivity() - it would do all the magic for me.

Comment: You might ask on the Gitter channel for MT, the author of that package hangs out there. I'm not sure, but I think it uses message header to transfer the activity identifiers to show a nested graph in AppInsights of all service interactions.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, link is broken